# Library for extracting zip on the fly

Tags: c++, c, zip, in-memory

I have a rather large ZIP file, which gets downloaded (cannot change the file). The quest now is to unzip the file while it is downloading instead of having to wait till the *central directory end* is received.
Does such a library exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote "pinch" a while back. It's in Objective-C but the method to decode files from a zip might be a way to get it in C++? Yeah, some coding will be necessary.

http://forrst.com/posts/Now_in_ObjC_Pinch_Retrieve_a_file_from_inside-I54
https://github.com/epatel/pinch-objc

Comment: That is quite cool, +1. (It does require that the source of the file supports something like http `Range`.)

Comment: I'm just wondering, whether it would be possible to search for header 0x04034b50 and then assume, it's a local file header (given that 0x08 is not set in flags). This way you would not have to wait for the end of file...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure such a library exists. Unless you are on a very fast line [or have a very slow processor], it's unlikely to save you a huge amount of time. Decompressing several gigabytes only takes a few seconds if all the data is in ram [it may then take a while to write the uncompressed data to the disk, and loading it from the disk may add to the total time].

However, assuming the sending end supports "range" downloading, you could possibly write something that downloads the directory first [by reading the fixed header first, then reading the directory and then downloading the rest of the file from start to finish]. Presumably that's how "pinch" linked in epatel's answer works.

Comment: As @epatel pointed out in his blog post, this is more a problem on Servers and Smartphones.